# how to take image from camera in fragment android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

when i take image from camera in alert in fragment the app rotation and remove the image
note : this fragment in another fragment not activity  .

```
 Intent picIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                       File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), 
                       "temp1.jpg");
                       Uri mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
                       picIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
                       ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(picIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                       String filePath = mImageCaptureUri.getPath();
              if (!filePath.isEmpty()){
                           addImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                           image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                           imagePr.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath));
                       }
```